# Sync AND Pull in a Git Repo

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

My interest is this: I'd like to set up a single homework repository to share with my students. The repository contains templates, specifications, and unit tests. Students derive from this repository, complete their homework, and push their changes for grading.

This past year I did this using Bitbucket. I created a public Git repository containing my files. They created private forks. Mostly this worked well.

My problem is this: whenever I make changes to my files (i.e., fix a bug in the unit tests), the students must actively sync with my original repo. Many students do not do this and do not see the updated files. I know at the shell they can execute

```
git remote add skeleton git@bitbucket.org:prof/profrepo.git
git pull skeleton master
```

but I'd like to use this in Eclipse and in my very early CS classes, where technological intimidation is an issue and utility scripts are not feasible. Even if we get the tools set up correctly, students still forget to grab the changes from my repository.

Is there a way I can integrate pulling from my original repo into the three-step pull-code-push workflow? Does Git support this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at git hooks...maybe something like a pre-receive hook. Check this link for more details: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: A pre-receive hook (and all server-sidehooks) is run on push. It seems that drawing from the original repo should be done on pull. The other hooks are client-side, which probably won't work in a class without a common development environment.